# How do I fix ImageMagick install error on MacPorts?

Tags: imagemagick, macports

I've been trying to install ImageMagick through MacPorts with no luck. After running `sudo port install ImageMagick`, I get the following error:

Computing dependencies for ImageMagickError: Unable to execute port: invalid command name "supported_archs"

I'm running Mac OSX 10.5 with the latest version of MacPorts. Anyone able to shed some light on this error?

Comment: Even though you say you have the latest, what does "port version" print?

Comment: I think this should be on Super User: http://superuser.com/search?q=macports+imagemagick

Comment: Thanks ergosys. That fixed it. I assumed I had the latest version after installing a binary, but it appears I needed to run selfupdate after installing the binary.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed issue by running `port selfupdate` through MacPorts and confirming latest version.